# SonarQube Runner fails on a file having comma in its name

Tags: sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarqube5.2

SonarQube: 5.2

Scanner For MSBuild: 1.0.2

Below line exists in FilesToAnalyze.txt deep inside .sonarqube folder

`...Help\User\Duplicating,_Renaming,_Deleting_a_Blueprint.htm`

And, `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end` throws below exception. Notice how file name is truncated just before first comma in file name.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The folder 'C:\<full\path>\Help\User\Duplicating' does not exist for '<sonar:key>:509A1B17-E264-4DF5-99FC-AF27D064FBC4' (base directory = <dir containing .sonarqube>)`

I decided to exclude the folder containing `Help\User\` by passing `/d:sonar.exclusions="**\<parentDir>\Help\**"`. This has no effect.

1. Is there an issue in Sonar Runner if file names contained comma?
2. Why doesn't sonar.exclusions have any effect?
3. Finally, log message states `ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging`. How do I pass -X switch to Sonar Runner from `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe`. Is it in the `begin` command or `end` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a known issue.
Please refer to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-199 for details as to when it will be fixed.

Comment: Do you have thoughts on bullet points 2 & 3 in my question? Thanks.

Comment: @dinesh-bolkensteyn It doesn't look like there has been any progress on this in over a year.  Any chance we can get an update on it?